# Node.js - How to get data from json file and use that data to set custom attributes in xml

Tags: node.js, xml-parsing

Well I want to read json file in my node.js code to update the XML tags in the given XML, suppose I have a file named as **object.json**, now I want to Get its data, data in object.json is

```
{
    "input": {
        "customClass": "input",
        "customModule": "abcInput",
        "customModuleProvider": "Whatever"
    },
    "button": {
        "customClass": "ViewController",
        "customModule": "Testing",
        "customModuleProvider": "target"
    }
}
```

I have tried to print data but I was not able to use that data to set attributes, I tried to set attributes for hard coded tags, code for that is

```
var DOMParser = new (require('xmldom')).DOMParser({ normalizeTags: { default: false } });
var express = require("express"),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require("body-parser-xml")(bodyParser);
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var builder = new xml2js.Builder({ standalone: { default: false } });
var app = express();
//Options of body-parser-xml module

app.use(bodyParser.xml({
    xmlParseOptions: {
        normalize: false,     // Trim whitespace inside text nodes
        normalizeTags: false, // Transform tags to lowercase
        explicitArray: false // Only put nodes in array if >1
    }
}));

//Post Method
app.post('/users', function (req, res, body) {

    //Parsing Request.Body
    var document = DOMParser.parseFromString(
        builder.buildObject(req.body).toString()
    );
    //Getting a list of elements whose name is being given
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName("TextView");

    //Changing Tag Name of Specific Elements
    for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
        node[i].tagName = "com.mycompany.projectname.TextView";
    }
   //Getting a list of elements whose name is being given
  var node = document.getElementsByTagName("com.example.usmanchattha.custom.TextView");
 //Setting attributes
for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
    node[i].setAttribute("android:id", "@+id / text2");
    node[i].setAttribute("android:text", "Custom Android Font");
    node[i].setAttribute("customfontdemo:chattha", "faizan");
    node[i].setAttribute("android:padding", "12dp");
    node[i].setAttribute("customfontdemo:fontName", "pipe_dream.ttf");
    node[i].setAttribute("android:textSize", "32sp");
}
    //Responsing Updated Data
    res.send(document.toString());
});
app.listen(1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I ran into same problem, and then after a hard work I made a solution for this problem, here is the code that I created, it works perfectly fine, if you have any query, please make sure to ask.

```
var express = require("express"),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var DOMParser = new (require('xmldom')).DOMParser({ normalizeTags: { default: false } });
var arrayOfControls = require('./object.json'); //to read object.json file
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: '*/*' }));

app.post('/users', function (req, res, body) {
    var document = DOMParser.parseFromString(
        req.body
    );
    var ControlNames = Object.keys(arrayOfControls); //Returns Control Names
    for (var singleControl = 0; singleControl < ControlNames.length; singleControl++) {
        var wholeObject = arrayOfControls[ControlNames[singleControl]]; //Returns Property names of index[i] control as an object
        var PropertyNames = Object.keys(wholeObject); //returns properties of first control    
        var listOfElements = document.getElementsByTagName(ControlNames[singleControl]);

        if (listOfElements.length < 0) {
            continue;
        } else {
            for (var singleElement = 0; singleElement < listOfElements.length; singleElement++) {
                for (var singleProperty = 0; singleProperty < PropertyNames.length; singleProperty++) {
                    listOfElements[singleElement].setAttribute(PropertyNames[singleProperty], wholeObject[PropertyNames[singleProperty]].toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    req.body = document.toString();
    res.send(document.toString());
});

app.listen(1000);
```